# UNet Segmentation, chest xray lung segmentation using Unet

Tags: python, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I want to segment a chest x ray images for lung using UNet model, I have image dataset in which size of each  image is (256, 256). When i am using the Unet model for segment it, it is showing error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model" (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 256, 256)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "model" (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256), dtype=uint8)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

What is the solution? The UNet model which i am using valid for dimension of (height, width, channel).

```
`#Build the model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)
#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
..........................`
```

I tried using the Unet with dimension (height, width) in that case it is showing error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_40" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 256, 256)
```

Please help, thanks`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the number of channels.
On CT images, there is usually only one channel (grey scale).

You give `shape=(None, 256, 256)`, but your model expects `shape=(None, 256, 256, 1)` ( as specified in `IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS`).

So you need to add one dimension to your tensor. To do so, you can use for example `tf.expand_dims(image, -1)`.

eg :

```py
>>> image = tf.zeros([10,256,256])
>>> image = tf.expand_dims(image, -1)
>>> image.shape.as_list()
[10,256,256,1]
```